# Getting Entity But null value properties in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am getting an entity by code and Getting the result from the Db using Hibernate.
The value exists but all the properties shows null and If I try to use the properties of the returned Entity object properties values those gets NULL. But Value actually exists.

The Order and Cart has extends one abstract class which has the common properties.
So below is the Entity and the code I have.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter @Setter
 public class AbstractOrder implements Serializable {

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "DeliveryAddressID")
  private Address deliveryAddress;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "BillingAddressID")
  private Address billingAddress;
  ....
  ....

 }

 public Order cloneCartToOrder(String cartCode,String sellerId) {
    Cart cart = cartDao.findByCode(cartCode);
    Order order=getOrderDetails(cartCode);
    List<PromotionResult> promotionResults = null;
    if(order==null) {
        order = modelMapper.map(cart, Order.class);
        order.setOrderDate(new Date());
        order.setCode(cart.getCode());
        order.setStatus("Open");
        order.setHowWasOrderConfirmed(HowOrderConfirmStatus.ESALE);
        setOrderAddress(order, cart);
        promotionResults = order.getPromotionResults().stream().map(promotionResult -> {
   ..........
   ..........
   ..........

}

private void setOrderAddress(Order order, Cart cart) {
    Address address = addressDao.getAddressById(cart.getBillingAddress().getId());
    if (order.getShippingSameAsInvoice()) {
        Address billAddress = createNewAddressForOrder(address);
        order.setBillingAddress(billAddress);
        order.setDeliveryAddress(billAddress);
    } else {
        Address billAddress = createNewAddressForOrder(address);
        Address deliveryAddress = createNewAddressForOrder(addressDao.getAddressById(cart.getDeliveryAddress().getId()));
        order.setBillingAddress(billAddress);
        order.setDeliveryAddress(deliveryAddress);
    }
}

private Address createNewAddressForOrder(Address address ) {
    Address newAddress = new Address();
    newAddress.setBusinessPhone(address.getBusinessPhone());
    newAddress.setCountry(address.getCountry());
    newAddress.setCompany(address.getCompany());
    newAddress.setEmail(address.getEmail());
    newAddress.setFirstName(address.getFirstName());
    newAddress.setLastName(address.getLastName());
    newAddress.setHomePhone(address.getHomePhone());
    newAddress.setIsBillingAddress(address.getIsBillingAddress());
    newAddress.setIsShippingAddress(address.getIsShippingAddress());
    newAddress.setLatitude(address.getLatitude());
    newAddress.setLongitude(address.getLongitude());
    newAddress.setMobile(address.getMobile());
    newAddress.setPostCode(address.getPostCode());
    newAddress.setState(address.getState());
    newAddress.setStreetAddress1(address.getStreetAddress1());
    newAddress.setStreetAddress2(address.getStreetAddress2());
    newAddress.setSuburb(address.getSuburb());
    newAddress.setTitle(address.getTitle());
    newAddress.setZone(address.getZone());
    return newAddress;
}
```

So if you see here I am calling this **setOrderAddress(order, cart);** method from the first method. and after that populating the Address to a new object to save it as a new address. But After saving I can see all the value I newly created is saved as Null only the Address created with ID.

Please see the PFA while inspect from the IDE.

[image: Screenshot taken while inspect]

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: @Andronicus I added the code. please review it.

Comment: Paste the `Order` and `Cart` entities, please

Comment: @Andronicus I have included the code. pleae have a look. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entities are lazily fetched (`FetchType.LAZY`), you would have to make them eager (`FetchType.EAGER`) or, if you care about performance in this case, you can write your own query to fetch them together with parent entity.

Comment: Like explicit DB call to fetch address based on Cart or Order ?

Comment: @Sachi-17 is that a question? I don't get that

Comment: Yes just for confirmation.

Comment: @Sachi-17 Yes, you can fetch it in a separate query, but that is a bit slower